# enforce Linear regression model to pass through specific points

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

I applied linear regression model without library but I need to enforce the model to pass through two points [X, Y] without using any libraries

[image]

this what I need the model do but without any python libraries

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50447/perform-linear-regression-but-force-solution-to-go-through-some-particular-data#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20force,done%20in%20a%20roundabout%20way.&text=Any%20two%20points%20can%20be,line%20to%20find%20the%20intercept.) should help.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore unfortunately this in R I tried to convert it to python but the code is not clear for the point I'm asking on it, thanks